Distorting a complex path uniformly in Illustrator 2024/5, ideally with Bézier curves
I have a complex (set of) path(s) that I am slicing up vertically into sections I need to pinch in two places. If this was a simple shape, like a rectangle, I can get the effect I want by:

selecting the bottom two handles and using the Scale tool to pinch the first angle,
adding additional handles at the points I want path to inflect,
doing step #1 again to bring them together,
merging the now overlapping bottom points,
and using the anchor point conversion tool to create the curves I want to achieve, like so:


The trouble is, I would like to perform this transformation on a rectangular strip of a complex path (which I have already cut into strips using the Pathfinder ➔ Divide tool):

I suspect (am hoping) there is a simple way for me to treat the rectangular strip as a rectangle itself, or some other way to achieve this effect.
I have tried using Effect ➔ Distort & Transform ➔ Free Distort, but that only allows me to distort to the first angle, and doesn’t exactly allow the precision I need to make sure the angle is correct.
I have contemplated Pathfinder ➔ Divide’ing the shapes again at the inflection point and running another Free Distort, then welding them back together, but that would be time consuming and wouldn’t allow me to curve the distortions. Not being able to curve the distortion may not be a deal-breaker, but I am hoping to find a solution that has that option if I need it now or in the future.
The path itself is only made up of the black portions, and the ultimate goal is to cut the distorted strips out of vinyl and apply them to a 3D surface. So any mutations on the shape with effects would ultimately have to be Expanded back to plain Path objects before cutting.

Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh

An Envelope Mesh essentially provides an unfettered "free distort", as a singular object, within the mesh.
Adding more rows or columns can make it easier initially. And you can always use the Mesh tool to add more mesh points or slide mesh point along their paths (yes slide the point, as opposed to moving the path.)

One may also find Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object helpful.
With the top object, you place a single, closed, shape above the objects you wish to distort, select it all, and then choose the menu item. The Mesh will be created to distort the below objects to match the shape of the top object.

Once the mesh is made, editing it is the same as editing any other mesh. Using Top Object effectively provides a shortcut to a specific shape.

Example images are quick and unrefined merely to show basic distortions as Envelope Meshes are created. Envelope Meshes apply a two-way distortion - base artwork will be squished or stretched to match the overall mesh shape.

Meshes can be far more complex in nature and some users struggle to grasp them quickly. However, once the logic of them "clicks", they become as easy to edit as any other object in Illustrator. So, if you are struggling initially to understand them, realize many do and patience will prove worthwhile. They are one of those features that many avoid due to their complexity, but they are also one of the most powerful features in Illustrator.
Adobe Help on meshes can explain further: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html
While the Adobe help focuses on Gradient Meshes, the overall usage regarding editing, adding, removing, moving, etc. points and paths is exceptionally similar to Envelope Meshes - the difference being Envelope Meshes aren't about color assignments.

As of this writing, SVG has no support for meshes - Gradient or Envelope. Artwork needs to be expanded if SVG is the final goal.

Thanks so much for your thorough response! I had forgotten that I’d looked at Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh previously, but could not make heads nor tails of it. I definitely think Make with Top Object is going to be it, since I can apply the same (duplicated) object to each strip. I’ll be exploring meshes for the foreseeable future.
